# What the select command will go back when something changed in the midway

Tags: sql-server

We have run the command `select * from table1` and it will last for a long time. Then, someone updates the data in `table1`. So, what we will get, the former data or the changed data?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `output` clause

Comment: @RajeevRanjan, I don't see how an `OUTPUT` clause relates to the question.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if someone updates the same table you're reading depends on isolation level you're running on. You can find the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but here's the key points:

- READ COMMITTED

  - Data can be changed by other transactions between individual statements within the current transaction, resulting in nonrepeatable reads or phantom data.
  - If READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is set to OFF (the default), the Database Engine uses shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying rows
  - If READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is set to ON, the Database Engine uses row versioning to present each statement with a transactionally consistent snapshot of the data as it existed at the start of the statement.
- REPEATABLE READ

  - No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes
- SNAPSHOT

  - The transaction can only recognize data modifications that were committed before the start of the transaction. Data modifications made by other transactions after the start of the current transaction are not visible to statements executing in the current transaction.
- SERIALIZABLE

  - No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.
  - Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction until the current transaction completes.

Comment: I suggest you add that no data modifications will be recognized in the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level when the database `READ_COMMITTED_SHAPSHOT` option is on. The behavior is similar to `SNAPSHOT` except statement-level rather than transaction level.